# How to configure Android Studio to recognize methods with SystemApi annotation

Tags: android-studio, rooted-device

It is possible to configure Android Studio to recognize and use methods with @SystemApi and @hide annotations? The app being developed will be used on a device with rooted permition

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using Android Hidden API:
https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api

Comment: Is it required root?